# Using VBA to cause my command button to transfer rows to second sheet dependent on dropdown in column B

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA, but it appears to do what I need it to do.

I have created a sheet with 68 rows of values.  The next column, a user will select from a drop down of 4 variables.

The command button will cause all selections from column A that were identified as "very important" in Column B to the next sheet for further use in decision making.

I am following the process that is used in the following video, as it is doing exactly what I am looking for, for this step.

https://youtu.be/qGZQIl9JJk4

However, when I do the Msgbox (a) to check that is working, I get Run time error "1004" Application-defined or object-defined error.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit the code into the question, instead of a video.

Comment: a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row

Comment: I hope that helps @Warcupine

Comment: ```x1up``` should be ```xlup``` as in excel. also ```Rows.count``` is a relative reference change it to ```Worksheets("sheet1").Rows.Count```

Comment: @Warcupine thank you.  I misread his l as 1.  It didn't seem to make a difference to the result (68) that I get by making the second change, but I have done so, and will hopefully be able to get to part 2 - taking the list of selected rows that meet the variable in question and creating a drop down selection of each versus each other in a 1-1 drop down box.  I will post how it goes.

Comment: Very grateful for your assistance.  Thank you. I would give you the green check mark, but I don't have that option - probably because I am a noob?